# Why is the mask border jagged when I paint on it?

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

When I paint on the border of the mask, the edge is jagged. I don't know how to fix it to make it smooth. I have uploaded the blender file for reference.
[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hj68wIjmgYM1tRh4T5D8lwWOQVCVoEqk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've activated the *Paint Mask* option in the *3D View*, it will limit the painting within the selected faces, it won't smooth the painting if it overflows these limits.

When you paint on an island, as you see in the following image the exact same thing will happen, except you can set a bleeding value that will make the color overflow the UV's limits, it will make the pixelization unnoticeable on your object (see image).

So I guess you can fix it by creating a separate island for the part you want to paint on and correct the borders in the *Image Editor* in *Paint* mode, or disable the *Paint Mask* option in the *3D View* and correct the painting manually (also there's Kalaakaar solution, you can perpendicularize the UVs in the *UV Editor*).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The UV Island for that mesh is somewhat diagonal. The actuals pixels of the texture are just the same regular grid though. So when you paint the pixels on this slanted UV map, you will see the diagonal pixel stairs thingy. To avoid this, there are two solutions.

1. Higher Resolution: 
   Not the best one. In fact very bad in some cases. You still will see the steps if you go close enough. But if were a complicated model and you did not wanted to do some more work in the UVs this is a quick and dirty solution.
2. UV Squares addon:
   This is a free addon which lets you convert your UVs to rectangular or square grids. If you select the Island, and convert it to a grid shaped one, the grid of pixels will now line up with the UVs and a straight line will always be a straight line.

A little trick: If you ever want to paint a design which is more diagonal, you can just make your UVs a grid, rotate the UVs and paint straight lines on the image texture. You will get clean diagonal lines. ;)